# SQL Update counter for given day's minute based on Duration (in sequence)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
;WITH dayCTE
AS
(
        SELECT 1 AS Time_ID, 
                CAST('2018-10-03' AS DATETIME) + CAST(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0, GETDATE()),0),120),5) AS DATETIME) AS [DT], 0 AS AtCnt
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Time_ID+1, 
                CAST('2018-10-03' AS DATETIME) + CAST(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), DATEADD(MINUTE, Time_ID*1, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0, GETDATE()), 0) ), 120), 5) AS DATETIME) AS [DT], 0 AS AtCnt
        FROM dayCTE
        WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, Time_ID*1,DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0, GETDATE()),0)) < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0, GETDATE())+1,0)
)
SELECT *
INTO dayInMin FROM dayCTE

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2000)

SELECT * FROM dayInMin;

--Another table
CREATE TABLE StatusDuration
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [StartDateTime] DATETIME,
    [Status] VARCHAR(10),
    [Duration] INT
)
GO

SELECT * FROM [StatusDuration]

INSERT INTO StatusDuration
VALUES
('2018-10-03 17:45:00.000', 'Green', 60),
('2018-10-03 17:59:00.000', 'Yellow', 2),
('2018-10-03 20:45:00.000', 'Cyan', 130),
('2018-10-03 22:50:00.000', 'Red', 65),
('2018-10-03 22:54:00.000', 'Orange', 6)

SELECT * FROM [StatusDuration]
```

Please suggest an effective query to update  the AtCnt for each minute starting from StatusDuration.dbo.StartDateTime till the Duration against the dayInMin.DT

e.g.

- For `Green` row, `AtCnt` will be updated to `1` starting 17:45 till 18:44 (for 60 min duration)
- `Yellow`: `AtCnt = 2` (since the previous one updated it to '1') starting 17:59 till 18:00 (for 2 min duration)
- `Cyan`: `AtCnt = 1` starting 20:45 till 22:54 (for 130 min duration)
- `Red`: `AtCnt = 2` starting 22:50 till 22:54 (due to previous update) and updated to '1' starting 22:55 till 23:54
- `Orange`: `AtCnt = 3` for 22:54 (due to previous updates) and updated to '2' starting 22:55 till 22:59

Desired Results below (excluding AtCnt = 0 ):

```
ID      DT                      AtCnt
1066    2018-10-03 17:45:00.000 1
1067    2018-10-03 17:46:00.000 1
1068    2018-10-03 17:47:00.000 1
1069    2018-10-03 17:48:00.000 1
1070    2018-10-03 17:49:00.000 1
1071    2018-10-03 17:50:00.000 1
1072    2018-10-03 17:51:00.000 1
1073    2018-10-03 17:52:00.000 1
1074    2018-10-03 17:53:00.000 1
1075    2018-10-03 17:54:00.000 1
1076    2018-10-03 17:55:00.000 1
1077    2018-10-03 17:56:00.000 1
1078    2018-10-03 17:57:00.000 1
1079    2018-10-03 17:58:00.000 1
**1080  2018-10-03 17:59:00.000 2
1081    2018-10-03 18:00:00.000 2**
1082    2018-10-03 18:01:00.000 1
1083    2018-10-03 18:02:00.000 1
1084    2018-10-03 18:03:00.000 1
1085    2018-10-03 18:04:00.000 1
1086    2018-10-03 18:05:00.000 1
1087    2018-10-03 18:06:00.000 1
1088    2018-10-03 18:07:00.000 1
1089    2018-10-03 18:08:00.000 1
1090    2018-10-03 18:09:00.000 1
1091    2018-10-03 18:10:00.000 1
1092    2018-10-03 18:11:00.000 1
1093    2018-10-03 18:12:00.000 1
1094    2018-10-03 18:13:00.000 1
1095    2018-10-03 18:14:00.000 1
1096    2018-10-03 18:15:00.000 1
1097    2018-10-03 18:16:00.000 1
1098    2018-10-03 18:17:00.000 1
1099    2018-10-03 18:18:00.000 1
1100    2018-10-03 18:19:00.000 1
1101    2018-10-03 18:20:00.000 1
1102    2018-10-03 18:21:00.000 1
1103    2018-10-03 18:22:00.000 1
1104    2018-10-03 18:23:00.000 1
1105    2018-10-03 18:24:00.000 1
1106    2018-10-03 18:25:00.000 1
1107    2018-10-03 18:26:00.000 1
1108    2018-10-03 18:27:00.000 1
1109    2018-10-03 18:28:00.000 1
1110    2018-10-03 18:29:00.000 1
1111    2018-10-03 18:30:00.000 1
1112    2018-10-03 18:31:00.000 1
1113    2018-10-03 18:32:00.000 1
1114    2018-10-03 18:33:00.000 1
1115    2018-10-03 18:34:00.000 1
1116    2018-10-03 18:35:00.000 1
1117    2018-10-03 18:36:00.000 1
1118    2018-10-03 18:37:00.000 1
1119    2018-10-03 18:38:00.000 1
1120    2018-10-03 18:39:00.000 1
1121    2018-10-03 18:40:00.000 1
1122    2018-10-03 18:41:00.000 1
1123    2018-10-03 18:42:00.000 1
1124    2018-10-03 18:43:00.000 1
1125    2018-10-03 18:44:00.000 1
1246    2018-10-03 20:45:00.000 1
1247    2018-10-03 20:46:00.000 1
1248    2018-10-03 20:47:00.000 1
1249    2018-10-03 20:48:00.000 1
1250    2018-10-03 20:49:00.000 1
1251    2018-10-03 20:50:00.000 1
1252    2018-10-03 20:51:00.000 1
1253    2018-10-03 20:52:00.000 1
1254    2018-10-03 20:53:00.000 1
1255    2018-10-03 20:54:00.000 1
1256    2018-10-03 20:55:00.000 1
1257    2018-10-03 20:56:00.000 1
1258    2018-10-03 20:57:00.000 1
1259    2018-10-03 20:58:00.000 1
1260    2018-10-03 20:59:00.000 1
1261    2018-10-03 21:00:00.000 1
1262    2018-10-03 21:01:00.000 1
1263    2018-10-03 21:02:00.000 1
1264    2018-10-03 21:03:00.000 1
1265    2018-10-03 21:04:00.000 1
1266    2018-10-03 21:05:00.000 1
1267    2018-10-03 21:06:00.000 1
1268    2018-10-03 21:07:00.000 1
1269    2018-10-03 21:08:00.000 1
1270    2018-10-03 21:09:00.000 1
1271    2018-10-03 21:10:00.000 1
1272    2018-10-03 21:11:00.000 1
1273    2018-10-03 21:12:00.000 1
1274    2018-10-03 21:13:00.000 1
1275    2018-10-03 21:14:00.000 1
1276    2018-10-03 21:15:00.000 1
1277    2018-10-03 21:16:00.000 1
1278    2018-10-03 21:17:00.000 1
1279    2018-10-03 21:18:00.000 1
1280    2018-10-03 21:19:00.000 1
1281    2018-10-03 21:20:00.000 1
1282    2018-10-03 21:21:00.000 1
1283    2018-10-03 21:22:00.000 1
1284    2018-10-03 21:23:00.000 1
1285    2018-10-03 21:24:00.000 1
1286    2018-10-03 21:25:00.000 1
1287    2018-10-03 21:26:00.000 1
1288    2018-10-03 21:27:00.000 1
1289    2018-10-03 21:28:00.000 1
1290    2018-10-03 21:29:00.000 1
1291    2018-10-03 21:30:00.000 1
1292    2018-10-03 21:31:00.000 1
1293    2018-10-03 21:32:00.000 1
1294    2018-10-03 21:33:00.000 1
1295    2018-10-03 21:34:00.000 1
1296    2018-10-03 21:35:00.000 1
1297    2018-10-03 21:36:00.000 1
1298    2018-10-03 21:37:00.000 1
1299    2018-10-03 21:38:00.000 1
1300    2018-10-03 21:39:00.000 1
1301    2018-10-03 21:40:00.000 1
1302    2018-10-03 21:41:00.000 1
1303    2018-10-03 21:42:00.000 1
1304    2018-10-03 21:43:00.000 1
1305    2018-10-03 21:44:00.000 1
1306    2018-10-03 21:45:00.000 1
1307    2018-10-03 21:46:00.000 1
1308    2018-10-03 21:47:00.000 1
1309    2018-10-03 21:48:00.000 1
1310    2018-10-03 21:49:00.000 1
1311    2018-10-03 21:50:00.000 1
1312    2018-10-03 21:51:00.000 1
1313    2018-10-03 21:52:00.000 1
1314    2018-10-03 21:53:00.000 1
1315    2018-10-03 21:54:00.000 1
1316    2018-10-03 21:55:00.000 1
1317    2018-10-03 21:56:00.000 1
1318    2018-10-03 21:57:00.000 1
1319    2018-10-03 21:58:00.000 1
1320    2018-10-03 21:59:00.000 1
1321    2018-10-03 22:00:00.000 1
1322    2018-10-03 22:01:00.000 1
1323    2018-10-03 22:02:00.000 1
1324    2018-10-03 22:03:00.000 1
1325    2018-10-03 22:04:00.000 1
1326    2018-10-03 22:05:00.000 1
1327    2018-10-03 22:06:00.000 1
1328    2018-10-03 22:07:00.000 1
1329    2018-10-03 22:08:00.000 1
1330    2018-10-03 22:09:00.000 1
1331    2018-10-03 22:10:00.000 1
1332    2018-10-03 22:11:00.000 1
1333    2018-10-03 22:12:00.000 1
1334    2018-10-03 22:13:00.000 1
1335    2018-10-03 22:14:00.000 1
1336    2018-10-03 22:15:00.000 1
1337    2018-10-03 22:16:00.000 1
1338    2018-10-03 22:17:00.000 1
1339    2018-10-03 22:18:00.000 1
1340    2018-10-03 22:19:00.000 1
1341    2018-10-03 22:20:00.000 1
1342    2018-10-03 22:21:00.000 1
1343    2018-10-03 22:22:00.000 1
1344    2018-10-03 22:23:00.000 1
1345    2018-10-03 22:24:00.000 1
1346    2018-10-03 22:25:00.000 1
1347    2018-10-03 22:26:00.000 1
1348    2018-10-03 22:27:00.000 1
1349    2018-10-03 22:28:00.000 1
1350    2018-10-03 22:29:00.000 1
1351    2018-10-03 22:30:00.000 1
1352    2018-10-03 22:31:00.000 1
1353    2018-10-03 22:32:00.000 1
1354    2018-10-03 22:33:00.000 1
1355    2018-10-03 22:34:00.000 1
1356    2018-10-03 22:35:00.000 1
1357    2018-10-03 22:36:00.000 1
1358    2018-10-03 22:37:00.000 1
1359    2018-10-03 22:38:00.000 1
1360    2018-10-03 22:39:00.000 1
1361    2018-10-03 22:40:00.000 1
1362    2018-10-03 22:41:00.000 1
1363    2018-10-03 22:42:00.000 1
1364    2018-10-03 22:43:00.000 1
1365    2018-10-03 22:44:00.000 1
1366    2018-10-03 22:45:00.000 1
1367    2018-10-03 22:46:00.000 1
1368    2018-10-03 22:47:00.000 1
1369    2018-10-03 22:48:00.000 1
1370    2018-10-03 22:49:00.000 1
**1371  2018-10-03 22:50:00.000 2
1372    2018-10-03 22:51:00.000 2
1373    2018-10-03 22:52:00.000 2
1374    2018-10-03 22:53:00.000 2
1375    2018-10-03 22:54:00.000 3
1376    2018-10-03 22:55:00.000 2
1377    2018-10-03 22:56:00.000 2
1378    2018-10-03 22:57:00.000 2
1379    2018-10-03 22:58:00.000 2
1380    2018-10-03 22:59:00.000 2**
1381    2018-10-03 23:00:00.000 1
1382    2018-10-03 23:01:00.000 1
1383    2018-10-03 23:02:00.000 1
1384    2018-10-03 23:03:00.000 1
1385    2018-10-03 23:04:00.000 1
1386    2018-10-03 23:05:00.000 1
1387    2018-10-03 23:06:00.000 1
1388    2018-10-03 23:07:00.000 1
1389    2018-10-03 23:08:00.000 1
1390    2018-10-03 23:09:00.000 1
1391    2018-10-03 23:10:00.000 1
1392    2018-10-03 23:11:00.000 1
1393    2018-10-03 23:12:00.000 1
1394    2018-10-03 23:13:00.000 1
1395    2018-10-03 23:14:00.000 1
1396    2018-10-03 23:15:00.000 1
1397    2018-10-03 23:16:00.000 1
1398    2018-10-03 23:17:00.000 1
1399    2018-10-03 23:18:00.000 1
1400    2018-10-03 23:19:00.000 1
1401    2018-10-03 23:20:00.000 1
1402    2018-10-03 23:21:00.000 1
1403    2018-10-03 23:22:00.000 1
1404    2018-10-03 23:23:00.000 1
1405    2018-10-03 23:24:00.000 1
1406    2018-10-03 23:25:00.000 1
1407    2018-10-03 23:26:00.000 1
1408    2018-10-03 23:27:00.000 1
1409    2018-10-03 23:28:00.000 1
1410    2018-10-03 23:29:00.000 1
1411    2018-10-03 23:30:00.000 1
1412    2018-10-03 23:31:00.000 1
1413    2018-10-03 23:32:00.000 1
1414    2018-10-03 23:33:00.000 1
1415    2018-10-03 23:34:00.000 1
1416    2018-10-03 23:35:00.000 1
1417    2018-10-03 23:36:00.000 1
1418    2018-10-03 23:37:00.000 1
1419    2018-10-03 23:38:00.000 1
1420    2018-10-03 23:39:00.000 1
1421    2018-10-03 23:40:00.000 1
1422    2018-10-03 23:41:00.000 1
1423    2018-10-03 23:42:00.000 1
1424    2018-10-03 23:43:00.000 1
1425    2018-10-03 23:44:00.000 1
1426    2018-10-03 23:45:00.000 1
1427    2018-10-03 23:46:00.000 1
1428    2018-10-03 23:47:00.000 1
1429    2018-10-03 23:48:00.000 1
1430    2018-10-03 23:49:00.000 1
1431    2018-10-03 23:50:00.000 1
1432    2018-10-03 23:51:00.000 1
1433    2018-10-03 23:52:00.000 1
1434    2018-10-03 23:53:00.000 1
1435    2018-10-03 23:54:00.000 1
```

Comment: The desired results as a table would help.

Comment: Stop thinking of _how to implement all at once_ and try to think of _overlapping sets_ which your task is about. If your skills let you writing recursive CTE, I guess you're familiar with `dateadd`, `join` and `group by`? Implement `select` statement first.